# Sampling from an Inverse Gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, gibbs, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am using Gibbs sampling in the MCMC estimation of a stochastic volatility model. One of the posterior distributions is an Inverse Gamma distribution.
I was struggling with the sampling procedure or to be precise with the link to the Gamma distribution. Is it true that to get $Y \sim IG(alpha,beta)$, I have to sample $X \sim Gamma(\alpha,1/\beta)$ and take $ Y = 1/X$? This is also inline with posts on mathworks.
However, I also read it up on wolfram and in my opinion they contradict themselves in the article (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseGammaDistribution.html).
From the paragraph *Background&Context* (which deals with the generalized gamma distribution though):
[image: From the paragraph *Background&Context*]

vs. the description from *Details* (specifically the fourth point):

[image]

Does this discrepancy arise due to the difference between the inverse gamma and the generalized inverse gamma?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This discrepancy arises because there are two different parameterizations of the Gamma distribution and each relate differently to the Inverse Gamma distribution.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), the two parameterizations for the Gamma distribution are differentiated by using $(k,\theta)$ and $(\alpha, \beta)$. 
$$\text{If } X \sim \text{Gamma}(k, \theta) , \,\,\,\, f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(k) \theta^k} x^{k-1} e^{x/\theta}\,.$$
$$\text{If } X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta) , \,\,\,\, f(x) = \dfrac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{x\beta}\,.$$

Here $\alpha$ and $k$ are exactly the same in the pdfs but $\theta$ is and $\beta$ are different. $\theta$ is called the scale parameter and $\beta$ is called the rate parameter. The relation between these two is that $\beta = 1/\theta$.

If $X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ where $\beta$ is the rate parameter, then $1/X \sim IG(\alpha, \beta)$.

If $X \sim \text{Gamma}(k, \theta)$, where $\theta$ is the scale parameter, then $1/X \sim IG(k, 1/\theta)$.

In both those cases, the pdf of the IG is the same. If $Y \sim IG(\alpha, \beta)$, then the pdf of $Y$ is always
$$f(y) = \dfrac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{-\alpha-1} e^{-\beta/x}.$$

Comment: I have two papers in front of me, where one indeed specifies the parameters of the inverse gamma as $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In the other paper they are named m and M instead. So, I assume there is no way to find out the terminology used by the authors by just looking at the expression $X \sim IG(p_1, p_2)$? Cause they neither call the latter parameter scale nor rate. Thank you!

Comment: If they have $IG(\alpha, \beta)$, there is no question as to what the pdf is, since there is only one parameterization for $IG$.

Comment: But from $IG(m,M)$ it's not that obvious, is it? Anyway, thank you very much (again)! I've been dealing with that issue for 3 weeks now... Finally, it's solved.

Comment: @mscnvrsy It is obvious even for $IG(m, M)$ because there is only one parametrization for IG. Its how it relates to Gamma that might be confusing. Given $Y \sim IG(m,M)$, $1/Y \sim Gamma(m, M)$ or $1/Y \sim Gamma(m, 1/M)$ depending on the parameterization for Gamma that you choose. But the pdf of the IG will not be different based on these parameterizations. I have edited my answer to explain this a little bit more.

Comment: But how can I infer whether they provide $\theta$ or $\beta$ just from the expression $X \sim IG(m,M)$ with neither the $(\alpha,\beta)$ nor the $(k,\theta)$ specification, nor the formula for the pdf? I think we're talking past each other right now

Comment: IF $X\sim IG(m,M)$ then $\beta = M$ and $\theta = 1/M$. Choose whichever one you want to use!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42774/discussion-between-mscnvrsy-and-greenparker).